# Goal of hiding header in 2 stages, can't even get one to hide

Tags: javascript, html, header, navbar, banner

I want my header (which is made up of a logo banner and a navbar) to hide when scrolling, but in two stages, first,the banner minimizes and then navbar moves to the top, and then the navbar hides as well. Well I can't even get them to hide at all let alone in 2 stages. I am a very novice coder, and am basically stumbling around until I get something right, but this project is starting to take too long. I've included a JSFiddle so you can see what I'm working with, and maybe it's something simple I'm missing.

```js
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
  if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
    didScroll = false;
  }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta) return;

    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight) {
      // Scroll Down
      $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
      // Scroll Up
      if (st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
        $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
      }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
  }
  /*Expandable Sticky Bar (Initial: Nov 1st, 2010)
   * This notice must stay intact for usage
   * Author: Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/
   * Visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
   */

jQuery.noConflict()

function expstickybar(usersetting) {
var setting = jQuery.extend({
  position: 'bottom',
  peekamount: 30,
  revealtype: 'mouseover',
  speed: 200
}, usersetting)
var thisbar = this
var cssfixedsupport = !document.all || document.all && document.compatMode == "CSS1Compat" && window.XMLHttpRequest //check for CSS fixed support
if (!cssfixedsupport || window.opera) return
jQuery(function($) { //on document.ready
  if (setting.externalcontent) {
    thisbar.$ajaxstickydiv = $('<div id="ajaxstickydiv_' + setting.id + '"></div>').appendTo(document.body) //create blank div to house sticky bar DIV
    thisbar.loadcontent($, setting)
  } else thisbar.init($, setting)
})
}

}
}



})
```

```css
@charset"utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  background: url(IMAGE/BACKGROUNDS/scratched-metal-background-DARK-1024x768.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  /*Used by Safari &amp; Chrome*/
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  /* Used by Firefox */
  -o-background-size: cover;
  /* Used by Opera */
  background-size: cover;
  /* All Modern Browsers */
  padding-top: 40px;
}
#header {
  height: 220px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav-up {
  top: -220px;
  // same as header height. use variables in LESS/SASS

}
#banner {
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
#nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  left: 0;
  top: 200PX;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#nav li {
  background-color: #666666;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 15%;
  width: calc(90%/6);
}
#nav li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1vw;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}
#nav li:first-child a {
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}
#nav li a:hover {
  color: #666666;
  background-color: #fff;
}
#content {
  top: 420px;
  float: left;
  width: 78.5%;
  height: 3000px;
}
#footer {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/hideheader.js"></script>
<script src="js/expstickybar.js">
</script>

<body>
  <header class="nav-down">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="banner">
        <img src="IMAGE/BANNER/WHITE-BANNER-TRULY-MODULAR-WHITE.png" width="1500" height="200" alt="banner" />
      </div>
      <div id="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="INDEX.html">HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="PRODUCTS.html">PRODUCTS</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="ABOUT.html">ABOUT US</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="WOTACBLOG.html">BLOG</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="WOTACFORUM.html">FORUM</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="SUPPORT.html">SUPPORT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="content">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, augue odio morbi ac consectetuer fusce ut, felis rutrum dignissim rhoncus velit. Aliquam ante ac sociis pede, scelerisque lectus vitae leo dolorem sollicitudin. Dolor dolor id vulputate, mollis purus nec ut accumsan quam
    consectetuer. Ut justo, neque enim velit bibendum ultricies, massa a consequat adipiscing turpis suspendisse, voluptas tellus imperdiet sodales quis wisi. Sit sit, ante et aliquet vestibulum ut vel mattis, placerat eros ante eget adipiscing ullamcorper,
    ornare maecenas molestie, eget ornare non neque libero tincidunt. Ac consectetuer ipsum suscipit urna mollis, amet et urna consequat etiam quam rhoncus, mauris integer torquent lorem, metus sem. Felis lorem imperdiet. Tempor leo pellentesque bibendum.
    Nonummy phasellus felis integer diam fusce, error mi suspendisse sit ipsum sed. Nisl duis morbi sed nullam, libero ridiculus, enim felis nunc neque a elit. In eleifend, auctor ante quam eu, sed urna, in convallis, tellus aptent et neque at. Pede hymenaeos
    egestas. Duis ac risus elit libero, sed ullamcorper ac arcu suscipit maecenas, nec mauris turpis. Nonummy luctus sem, vestibulum lorem viverra aenean risus ipsum arcu, etiam amet erat sed et vestibulum et, porttitor nonummy luctus. Quis eget ligula
    egestas, sed malesuada laoreet, diam nec nonummy morbi nostra condimentum tortor, orci sit. Senectus tellus, erat neque rhoncus id praesent pharetra, wisi venenatis et varius, rutrum aliquam a bibendum nibh id dignissim. Quis erat litora aenean nibh
    ac, nec eu eleifend est, in fermentum neque sed mollis lobortis, wisi scelerisque urna senectus augue viverra, sit elit. Lectus pharetra vestibulum, varius integer, suspendisse dolor rutrum tincidunt pulvinar, et lobortis lacus mus egestas semper,
    dui amet elit massa. Aliquam sem nam sed, consectetuer est, quis elementum imperdiet tincidunt. In sed, nunc sem sit duis et lacus libero, sed vel a, auctor porta orci ut et nec sodales, quo libero massa duis blandit. Risus et ut, tellus morbi suspendisse
    sed velit, nonummy neque sodales integer ac nulla pede. Egestas molestie fusce luctus eu, justo sit, luctus sed libero augue eros risus sit, metus leo cras, orci sit. Vestibulum suspendisse pellentesque sagittis dolor. Suscipit est wisi, maecenas
    ridiculus pellentesque commodo ligula in, hendrerit et neque consequat amet blandit rutrum, ut congue. Congue duis proin fermentum nibh, nam in sem. Id rutrum, integer dui mauris, odio cras vulputate nunc. Sociis eget, mi turpis laoreet ut lorem habitant
    aliquam, sed porttitor praesent nec, in dolor, bibendum aenean molestie reiciendis pellentesque volutpat. Duis dui tristique, donec justo mauris fusce quis, "</div>
  <?php include_once( "analyticstracking.php") ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i was going to edit this and make the jsfiddle a link and bring the code over, but there's loads of it, please can you reduce your example down to the bit that causes the problem and post :-)

Comment: I got rid of all the excess [link](https://jsfiddle.net/mycetpy0/1/)

Comment: From what I could tell, that expstickybar code was jacking up jQuery's `$`, so every iteration of the interval didn't know what `$(this)` was. Inspector is your friend... check for JS errors and debug from there.

Comment: added the code into post